# Trigger a .cfg file from VBA code inside Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Name of the .cfg file: SmokeTest.cfg
Location of .cfg file: Desktop

Want to trigger from an excel using VBA code?
Already tried with "Shell" like below:

```
a = Shell("C:\Users\Desktop\SmokeTest.cfg", 0)
```

But didn't work

Expect to trigger the .cfg file from excel using the VBA code

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format but ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Users\Desktop\SmokeTest.cfg" might work

Comment: No @andrewb didn't work....

Comment: The program that opens (if any) depends on what program is associated with that extension. Are you sure your computer has the CFG extension associated with a valid executable?

Comment: `C:\Users\Desktop` is missing a Username as well, unless the user's name is "Desktop" and you are putting the file in a very odd location.

Comment: What's the content of that file? What should that file do? When should that file be triggered? ...?